# The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found after installing Visual Studio Xamarin and building default app

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, compiler-errors

I installed the latest version of Visual Studio with Xamarin, created a default app, and am getting a compilation error. Why is this not working out of the box? Here is the error:

> Error CS0246
> The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> TestApp.Android   C:\Users\matth\source\repos\TestApp\TestApp\TestApp.Android\MainActivity.cs 19  Active

Comment: Have you restored Nuget packages?

Comment: Not sure what that means. I'm a junior developer getting familiar with the software before starting new job. I just freshly installed VS and Xamarin, so I'm confused why building a new app from the provided template is not working.

Comment: Nuget is a very common tool for ant type of .Net development, so you should familiarize yourself with it.  Http://Nuget.org

Comment: Good idea, I'll start reading up on that and mark as resolved if it works. I'm installing an older version at the moment.

Comment: Once you load your solution, right click on solution explorer and “restore nuget packages”

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for future errors, but it worked after installing a different version. Very strange. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Like Jason said, restoring NuGet packages is a good idea, but I found a solution before trying that. I had to uninstall VS and delete all associated files, then install a different version. Not sure what was causing the issue.